# Проблема c батареей в ноутбуке, ОС Windows 10

Tags: windows, железо, ос

Вчера появился такой значок, с надписью "Батарея отсутствует" , никогда такого не было.
Без зарядки ноутбук работает, думаю что аккумулятор живой, возможно проблема в Винде.( устанавливал вчера только pyCharm, Python 3.8.1)[image: Батарея отсутсвует]

Comment: такое бывает на ноутбуках делл. В какой то момент они решают, что их родная зарядка - не их. И батарею заряжать не хотят (якобы зарядка может быть слабая и вряд ли хватит на все). И через какое то время батарея умирает. Полностью. И больше ее не видно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чаще всего это всё же железная проблема. Например бывало такое из за окисления интерфейсных контактов на шлейфе в встроенных акб, или при неисправности контроллера в самом акб. В первом случае иногда достаточно вытащить и обратно вставить шлейф.

Что бы исключить винду, можно [загрузить какую нибудь систему с флешки](https://zedpost.ru/47-operacionnaya-sistema-na-fleshke-za-5-minut-eto-vozmozhno.html) и посмотреть на индикацию там.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ